# write HDF h5 dataset (via h5py) which is a mix of string and numpy list

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py

I have the following two datasets (I have several of these `tuples`):

```
filename_string: "something"
filename_list: [1,2,3,4,5] # this is a numpy array.
```

Id like to know how to write this in a compact format via h5py. The goal is to have the end user read this h5 datafile and be able to deduce the list and its corresponding filename.

I am able to efficiently write the numpy list to h5, but strings seems to be a big problem and errors out when I include this.

Any help would be great - wasted a few hours looking for a solution!

Comment: I can imagine naming a `dataset` "something".  Or assigning the `filename_string` as an attribute of the dataset.

Comment: Normally when people have errors, we expect to see the problem code and the full error message.  It's usually easier to help with specific problems, than to suggest a whole new approach that the poster might have already tried.

Comment: Ditto on "share your code". How are you writing the string? As an Attribute? or in a array with string dtype or a record array (field dtype is a string)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This little scrap of code will create a dataset  named `something` (from the variable `filename_string`) that contains the data in your list `filename_list`.

```
import h5py
filename_string= "something"
filename_list= [1,2,3,4,5]

with h5py.File('SO_63137136.h5','w') as h5f:
    h5f.create_dataset(filename_string, data=filename_list)
```

Comment: yes, this is what I did eventual;ly.. I was iniitially attempting a harder challenge: write a tuple in HD5 which looks like so:` ("the_string", [the_list_elements])` anyways, this seems like it is not possible. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: If you reorganize your data, you can write it as a HDF5 dataset. HDF5 supports mixed datatypes in a dataset (as a NumPy recarray). This assumes the field that holds "the_string" can be a fixed string length, and the [the_list_elements] can be converted to a NumPy array (of common dtype: int, float or string).